# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render REACT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect

I have an issue, I'm trying to set a value to a state (selectedPathway) regarding the another const (countryLabel) that is set via redux.

Once "selectedPatway" is set, I would like to display the result in `<Select value={selectedPathway} />` This Select is return by the main component that surround all the logic.

Everything works well but when I refresh the page I get a "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" in the browser. Here is the code:

```
 const DefaultValue = () => {
    let matchingOption = options.find((option) => option.value.includes(countryLabel))
    let optionSelected = options.find((option) => option.value === value)
  
    const [selectedPathway, changeSelectedPathway] = useState(matchingOption)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      let test = []
      if(matchingOption) {
        test = matchingOption
      } else {
        test = options[0]
      }
      changeSelectedPathway(test)
      
    },[countryLabel])

    useEffect(() => {
      changeSelectedPathway(optionSelected)
    },[value])

     return selectedPathway
  }

return (
   <Select
       value={DefaultValue()}
   />
)
```

I've looked all over the internet, and I think that I've applied everything correctly (well obviously not as it is not working...).

- Not call hook conditionally
- Use hook at top level

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not causing this explicit error, `countryHasChanged` and `UsePrevious` are both hooks (because they call other hooks), but not written as those. Hooks **have** to start with `use` with a lower-case `u`. Generally, I'd recommend you enable eslint and the the react hooks eslint rules (probably preconfigured if you are using create-react-app) since that extension will probably tell you about a ton of other hooks violation in your project and will finally also show you the place where your hook violation triggering this error originates from.

Also, give the [Rules of Hooks documentation page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) a re-read.